# Can't get array of links in bootstrap popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover, bootstrap-popover

I'm trying to make a search option in a popover.

I load these popovers using AJAX into the page.

My popover code:

```
$(function () {
    $('body').on('click','.popup1',function(){
            var  windowid = this.id;
            $(".popup1").popover({
                title: "Kies product",
                content: '<input type="text"class="form-control" id="search" name="ProductSearch"  autocomplete="off" /><div id="searchable" class="list-group" style="margin-bottom: 0px;><div class="personScroll"><?php foreach($products as $d):?><a id="' + windowid + '" class="list-group-item" onclick="Sending1(<?=$d->productid?>,this.id);" href="javascript:;"><?=$d->titel?></a><?php endforeach;?></div>',
                html: true,
                trigger: 'manual',
                placement: "top",
                template: '<div class="popover personchoose"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="popover-inner"><h3 class="popover-title"></h3><div class="popover-content"><p></p></div></div></div>'
            });
            $(this).popover('toggle');
            $(".popup1").on('shown.bs.popover', function (e) {
                Search();
                $(".hideable").not(e.target).popover("hide");
                });
        });
```

});

My search function:

```
function Search() {
                var $rows = $('#searchable div a');
                $('#search').keyup(function () {
                    var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

                    $rows.show().filter(function () {
                        var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
                        return !~text.indexOf(val);
                    }).hide();
                });
            };
```

It can't find the rows , and I don't know why. Can anyone help me with fixing this method or giving an other option?

Tnx.